# PDFJS - getPageTextContent() is returning redundant content

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

[image]

I have tried calling the method getPageTextContent() of PDF JS but in few scenarios it is returning redundant text contents.

Repeating text not all the cases but few.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe the PDF actually _contains_ redundant text content‽

Comment: I checked the same opening the PDF in Chrome & FF and getting repeated contents but in IE it is handled good.